# Fancybox link triggering download?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fancybox-2

I am using [Fancybox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/) and [Justified Gallery](http://miromannino.github.io/Justified-Gallery/) on my site.  When I test locally, opening videos on the site works fine.  But when I deploy the app, it seems like clicking on a video triggers a download (which you can test here):

http://bip-android-test.herokuapp.com/projects/481/gallery

Any ideas about what might be causing this?

Comment: The fancybox loads the images correctly, but the videos are not working. I don't think that fancybox supports mp4 videos like this. I know they support youtube and vimeo.

Comment: I'm able to get videos to work with fancybox (for example, you can see the videos here: http://bip-android-test.herokuapp.com/projects/481)

Comment: Now that I see a working version, I noticed that there is no <video> object on that broken page. It looks like you need the <video> object with the sources (like you do on the working page).

Comment: I don't think that should matter - the href attribute of the link should define the behavior of the fancybox.  I don't want the video to load except when in the fancybox.

Comment: works fine for me, i just see a video load inside the fancybox

Comment: @chiliNUT what browser are you using?  when I use safari, chrome, and firefox on mac, they all seem to trigger a download

Comment: Chrome 42 and FF 35 on PC. Lol IE9 crashes and burns. Maybe its a mac/pc thing?

Comment: Just tried it on PC.  Firefox works for me, but Chrome tries to download the video...

Comment: hm, changed the videos from mp4 to webm and it got rid of the error (?!)

Comment: For cross-browser/cross-device compatibility, you may want to read http://www.picssel.com/play-mp4-videos-with-mediaelement-js-in-fancybox/ and check the demo http://www.picssel.com/demos/play_videos_with_mediaelement_in_fancybox.html